# How to pass variable onto another route in FLASK

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to pass a variable from one route to another, but I am unable to. Can someone guide me on doing it? I get the error on the last line.

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():

    if request.method == 'GET':

        return render_template('search.html', navbar=True)

    else:

        query = request.form.get('query').lower()
        query_like = '%' + query + '%'

        books = db.execute('SELECT * FROM books WHERE (LOWER(isbn) LIKE :query) OR (LOWER(title) LIKE :query) '
                           'OR (LOWER(author) LIKE :query)',
                           {'query': query_like}).fetchall()

        if not books:
            return render_template('error.html', message='No Books were Found!', navbar=True)

        return render_template('books.html', query=query, books=books, navbar=True)

@app.route("/books", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def books():

    return render_template('books.html', query=query, books=books)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback, I can't see what the error is or how you're trying to pass a variable between views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way your code is organized. Variables in a function are *scoped* within the function, so `books` isn't available from the second route. In addition to that, you have a *naming collision* where `books=books` is referring to the function itself (which is defined at the module scope).

If you want to share code between routes, put it in a separate function:

```
def get_books(query, show_nav_bar=False):
    query = query.lower()
    query_like = '%' + query + '%'
    books = db.execute('SELECT * FROM books WHERE (LOWER(isbn) LIKE :query) OR (LOWER(title) LIKE :query) '
                    'OR (LOWER(author) LIKE :query)', {'query': query_like}).fetchall()

    if not books:
        return render_template('error.html', message='No Books were Found!', navbar=True)

    return render_template('books.html', query=query, books=books, navbar=show_nav_bar)


@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('search.html', navbar=True)

    else:
        return get_books(request.form.get('query'), show_nav_bar=True)


@app.route("/books", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def books():
    return get_books(request.form.get('query'))
```

Comment: Well now, after logging in it, nothing shows up, just the circle showing the page is loading.